# ERROR ITMS-90098 when trying upload ipa in App Store Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, app-store

I try upload my swift app in App Store and the "Submit to App Store" process give me this error:

`ERROR ITMS-90098:` "This bundle is invalid. The key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` contains value 'arm64' which is incompatible with the `MinimumOSVersion` value of '8.0'."

If I change the "iOS Deployment Target" to 8.3 the message change to:

`ERROR ITMS-90098:` "This bundle is invalid. The key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` contains value 'arm64' which is incompatible with the `MinimumOSVersion` value of '8.3'."

My `Info.plist` include "Required device capabilities" `arm64` and `armv7`

The project include `Alamofire` and Cocoa Pods.

Somebody help me?

Regards

Comment: it can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/32900712/1067147

Answer (score 6):

When I archived my project I had my iPhone 6 plugged in. Archiving without any device attached fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Those keys don't work the way you think they do : it's an AND not an OR. By including the `arm64` key you are saying your app is for 64-bit devices only, which is not allowed on iOS 8.
Delete the `arm64` key.

Apple said at `WWDC` that `64-bit`-only iOS apps will be allowed on iOS 9, but you'd need to be building with `XCode 7` and targeting iOS 9.

You can also give those keys true and false values, which makes things more complicated. See Apple's docs if you want to know more. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html

Comment: Thanks w0mbat. But I don't understand yet, if remove arm64 from Info.plist the error change to ERROR ITMS-90502: "Invalid Bundle. Apps that only contain the arm64 slice must also have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist. You can help me?

Comment: Oh I see. It's not jsut the plist - you really are only compiling for ARM64. That is not allowed on iOS 8. Change your build settings and set the Architecture/Architectures setting to standard, which will make it compile for ARM7 and ARM64.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for citing apple's document.